# Method Not Found with 405 status

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have created Web API in ASP.NET, first I have created Controllers and by scaffolding, I have created the empty UI and change the RoutingConfig file, after that I have created the **WebApi 2 Controller-Empty**, wrote two methods, 
1) Get Method 2) Post Method  .... the Get method working fine when I am calling from My Jquery ajax but it will not work for Post method.

I am getting Method Not Found with 405 status code.[I have attached the error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLi1c.png)

Comment: The information in your question is very generic. It would be very hard to identify the issue.
please refer: https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/405-method-not-allowed
Mostly check if your server side has the method as POST and your ajax is sent as POST method.

Comment: It would help you could post code snippets of both your web api code and jquery.

Comment: please post your api code and ajax call so that we can help you

Comment: Ajax call =>     function MyMethod() {
        var guid = "abc";                 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/webApi/Post',
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset='UTF-8'",
            data: '{"data":"' + guid + '"}',                              //JSON.stringify(jsonString)
            datatype: "text",
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    }   (webapi Controller) public string post(string data) { return data; }

Comment: @NITESHKUMAR have you decorated your WebApi2 controller with `[HttpPost]` attribute? Secondly is your method `public` ?

Comment: @vibs2006 yes...

Comment: HTTP status code 405 is Method Not ___Allowed___ as can be seen from your screenshot. This is different from 404 Not ___Found___

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ajax call
  function MyMethod() {
        var guid = document.getElementById("guid").value;
        var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var jsonString = '{"Id": "'+guid+'","firstname":"'+fname+'" ,"lastname": "'+lname+'"}';

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/WebApi/Post',
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset='UTF-8'",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonString),
            datatype:"text",
            success: function () {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });

// WebApi Controller

        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody]string data) {

            Console.Write(data);
            return "Hello";
        } 
[Output of the program][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJtqZ.png
```